# Uniquely assign predicted objects/regions to groundtruth objects/regions

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, object-detection

I have a list of groundtruth objects (blue; 1-4) and a list of predicted objects (red; a-d). To calculate metrics for evaluating the performance of the prediction, I need to assign predicted objects to groundtruth objects. No object should be used twice!

The graphic shows on the right some possible solutions (X, Y, Z) to the problem, where purple areas indicate the overlap between to matched objects.

[image]

To implement this, I created an intersection matrix that contains intersections (with an overlap ratio [Intersection/Union]) of all objects. For the visualized example it would look sth like below (e.g. meaning obj_2 overlaps 0.3 with obj_a, 0.1 with obj_b, 0.3 with obj_c, and so forth ...):

```
    intersection_matrix

      | a   b   c   d
    --|-----------------
    1 | 0.1 -   -   -
    2 | 0.3 0.1 0.3
    3 | -   -   0.8 -
    4 | -   -   -   0.5
```

The constraint that **each object is used only once** translates to each row and column having at maximum one entry. I first thought this is straightforward, but having it given a bit of thought, I find this quite hard to solve in an optimal way.

As a straightforward implementation I started with an algorithm iterating over groundtruth-objects and assigning the one with the max "score".

```
for i = 1:length(groundtruth_objects)
   highest_overlap = max(intersect_matrix(i,:));
   % take prediction_object with highest overlap as match
   match = find(intersect_matrix_iou(i,:) == highest_overlap);

   % remove matched objects from intersect_matrix (to avoid further matches)
   intersect_matrix(i,:) = 0;        % remove groundtruth_object
   intersect_matrix(:,match) = 0;    % remove prediction_object

   % save matched pair as entry in match matrix (which is the solution)
   match_matrix(i,match) = highest_overlap;
end
```

This leads to Solution X, which can be really bad as demonstrated in the example. Iterating over prediction_objects instead leads to Solution Y, which is quite good here but can equally bad.

```
    Solution X              Solution Y              Solution Z

      | a   b   c   d         | a   b   c   d         | a   b   c   d
    --|-----------------    --|-----------------    --|-----------------
    1 | 0.1 -   -   -       1 | -   -   -   -       1 | 0.1 -   -   -
    2 | -   -   0.3 -       2 | 0.3 -   -   -       2 | -   0.1 -   -
    3 | -   -   -   0.1     3 | -   -   0.8 -       3 | -   -   0.8 -
    4 | -   -   -   -       4 | -   -   -   0.5     4 | -   -   -   0.5
```

**Problem** is, that to determine whether a match is really suited for an object, it makes sense to check whether the same candidate wouldn't match better on another object (where it has a higher score or which might otherwise not be covered at all). But there it quickly gets complicated, as shown in the left of the graphic:

- To judge whether to match obj_1 -> obj_a, we need to check obj_a, which also could match obj_2.
- To judge on that, we need to check obj_b and obj_c, where the latter could also obj_3.
- To judge on that, we need to check obj_d, which could also match obj_4 ...

I think for an optimal solution, one needs to progress iteratively, like indicated in the graphic.

A possible (and meaningful) rule stating optimality would be

1. match the prediction obj with highest score ...
2. ... AS LONG as this doesn't prevent higher matches on other objects
3. maybe protected by a threshold to avoid bad matches like

So far my thoughts on this. My questions now are:

- **Does this correspond to a known (and well-described and solved) algorithmic problem?**
- **Are there already algorithms/implementations for
  this problem?**
- **Or does anyone have an idea how to implement this in a
  finite and efficient way?**

Answer (score 0):

1. **Does this correspond to a known (and well-described and solved) algorithmic problem?**

Yes, this is an [Assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem).

2. **Are there already algorithms/implementations for this problem?**

The [Hungarian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) is an algorithm designed to solve assignment problems. It allows to involve a certain score/priority which could be represented by the overlap here.

3. **Or does anyone have an idea how to implement this in a finite and efficient way?**

There are several implementations in various languages. A MATLAB implementation that might be suited in this case is [this one](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6543-functions-for-the-rectangular-assignment-problem).